# Sigabrt error in [self.window makeKeyAndVisible] while running the app on ipad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, sigabrt

I am having an error in the following lines if code. This error is being generated when I run the app on ipad its working fine on the simulator.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Please elaborate the reasons why this error is being generated.

Comment: Whats your target, why dont you use ARC?

Comment: Thanks Anoop I got the solution. I was not setting the development target right. Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: So should I post that as an answer?

Comment: Yes you can please go a head and thanks for your support...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly check the Target... if you have set or not, and also the proper one.

And one suggestion, try to adopt ARC. That will make you feel ReeeelaaaaXXXX!!!